# In-house distribution

Tags: ios, enterprise

Where I'm wrong? I have enterprise account for distribution when i start to generate provision profile for my app I find provision only for `Ad-hoc` (when I must check `UDID` of my test device), but I want gave this app for my client without his `UDID` entering.
Can someone explain what I must do to make this app working on device of client 
I read official documentation but can't fined answer [there](https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/). 
Also I'm trying to find answer on stack but without any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what it should look like if you are creating a provisioning profile

[image: apple developer portal provisioning profile]

Please note that the enterprise "Team" is different to your normal app store developer "Team". You should have to choose the one you want where you log in to your apple developer id. (In case your developer apple id is the same for both "Teams", and of course you have multiple "Teams" in your developer account)

Comment: So, i have n't it. But may be for this i must registered something else? Only Ap-Store and Ad-hoc.
But my account is enterprise (i pay 299$)

Comment: If you can select "Ap Store" then it's no enterprise account. You can't do that with an enterprise account. As I said before, development Teams and enterprise Teams are different, so make sure you log in into the correct account/team.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide an UDID of devices you wish to test the app on, and make an AdHoc distribution profile with those devices included. Then you can archive the app and send it via email for the client to install it via iTunes, or send him the app through http://testflightapp.com/.